# What's meaning of set CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER = array('Connection: Close') in curl

Tags: post, curl

I need use curl to send a post request,but i don't know what's meaning of the follow statement

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));`,thank's advance

Comment: It just adds HTTP Header `Connection: Close`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this quote will answer your question:

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response. For example, **Connection: close** in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1) after the current request/response is complete.

<kbd>[**read more here**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.10)</kbd>